# How to replace string in URL with captured regex pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to replace 'hoge' to 'foo' with regex. But the user's value is dynamic so I can't use `str.gsub('hoge', 'foo')`.

```
str = '?user=hoge&tab=fuga'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Your question is an XY problem. You're asking about Y but need to ask about X, which would be, "How do I manipulate URLs with parameters."

Comment: I heard 'XY problem' for the first time. I learned something new. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this with a regular expression.

This is how to manipulate URIs using the existing wheels:

```
require 'uri'

str = 'http://example.com?user=hoge&tab=fuga'
uri = URI.parse(str)
query = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h # => {"user"=>"hoge", "tab"=>"fuga"}
query['user'] = 'foo'
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(query)
uri.to_s # => "http://example.com?user=foo&tab=fuga"
```

Alternately:

```
require 'addressable'

uri = Addressable::URI.parse('http://example.com?tab=fuga&user=hoge')
query = uri.query_values # => {"tab"=>"fuga", "user"=>"hoge"}
query['user'] = 'foo'
uri.query_values = query
uri.to_s # => "http://example.com?tab=fuga&user=foo"
```

Note that in the examples the order of the parameters changed, but the code handled the difference without problems.

The reason you want to use [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) or [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) is because parameters and values have to be correctly encoded when they contain illegal characters. URI and Addressable know the rules and will follow them, whereas naive code assumes it's OK to not bother with encoding, causing broken URIs.

URI is part of the Ruby Standard Library, and Addressable is more full-featured. Take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below regex

```
([?&]user=)([^&]+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iaKH4c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to find out what the user query maps to first before using a `.gsub` to replace whatever value it is.

First, parse the URL string into an URI object using [**the URI module**](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse). And then, you can use the CGI query methods to get the key value pairs of the query params off the URI object using [**the CGI module**](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-parse). And finally, you can `.gsub` off the values in that hash.

Comment: Why use both URI and CGI? Why use `gsub` at all if URI and CGI are being used?

Comment: @theTinMan it seems OP wants the original string just with that param value changed. Very specific ask lol